# Disable semantic in derived modes

Tags: emacs, emacs-semantic

How can I stop `semantic-mode` from clobbering buffer-local variables in derived modes? In my case I want semantic in C/C++, but I don't want it to setup in modes derived from these. Currently, I use semantic for the following

```
(setq semantic-new-buffer-setup-functions
      '((c-mode                . semantic-default-c-setup)
        (c++-mode              . semantic-default-c-setup)
        (srecode-template-mode . srecode-template-setup-parser)))
```

and attempt to disable it with

```
(add-to-list 'semantic-inhibit-functions
             (lambda () (not (memq major-mode '(c-mode c++-mode srecode-template-mode)))))
```

However, if I enter a derived mode, like `bison-mode`, semantic still runs its setup since it is hooked into c/c++, clobbering any variables I set in my `bison-mode-hook`, in this case `imenu-create-index-function`. How can I stop `semantic` from setting up derived modes?

Comment: Instead of `memq`, use `derived-mode-p`.

Comment: `derived-mode-p` is true for the parent mode as well. Even if I disable `semantic-mode` in a mode's hook and define  `imenu-create-index-function` in that same hook, it is still being set in the buffer

Comment: If you want only derived but not equal to the parent: `(and (derived-mode-p (not eq ...) ...))`.

Comment: but that function is supposed to return `t` for everything except those specific major modes. I don't think there is anything wrong with the way I have it.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `(and (derived-mode-p ...) (not (eq ...)) ...)`.

Comment: Sorry I think I worded it poorly, that function is supposed to be true for every mode except those three. The problem is semantic seems to clobber buffer-local variables when derived modes run parent mode hooks and I'm trying to figure a way around that

Comment: A major mode always kills all local variables when it is turned on.